# How Can I translate EasyUI DateBox

Tags: jquery-easyui

I want to translate the easyui datebox english words to another languages (browser language).
as you see in the attached picture below month names, days shortcuts and 'today' 'close' words, I want to change it to the browser language.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can open your jeasyui library folder , see trough folder ,  there is a locale folder , you can copy one of them and translate it.

[image: locale folder]
[image: example for En Langugange]